# Change a column value (Without actually updating it in the database) and list multiple rows as column values on one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I'm using a Heroku dataclip to quickly monitor information.
This SQL piece:

```
SELECT name, owner, id AS guild 
FROM rooms JOIN guilds ON rooms.name=guilds.room 
ORDER BY rooms.name DESC
```

Gives me

[image]

How can I change it so that all the `guild`s that share the same `name` are listed under it with the `guild` that matches `owner` having an asterisk next to it? (I want to remove the owner column this way)

Basically,

```
Testing
    422950512657432578
    431220877250658305*
BFClannet
    337583271787626503*
    216908635987509249
```

Or something along those lines.

EDIT: (Maybe each `name` should be a column and the `guilds` should be listed under the column as separate rows)

Comment: `case` expression

Answer (score 0):

If your exact output must be that, you could so something like this:

```
with data as (
  select 'Testing' as name, 431220877250658305 as owner, 422950512657432578 as guild union all
  select 'Testing' as name, 431220877250658305 as owner, 431220877250658305 as guild union all  
  select 'BFClannet' as name, 337583271787626503 as owner, 337583271787626503 as guild union all  
  select 'BFClannet' as name, 337583271787626503 as owner, 216908635987509249 as guild
)
select 
  case 
    when owner=0 then name 
    else '  ' ||
      case when owner=guild then cast(owner as varchar(100)) || '*' else cast(guild as varchar(100)) end
   end
from (
  select name, owner, guild from data union all
  select distinct name, 0, 0 from data
  ) kk
order by name,owner
```

You can test it here: https://rextester.com/ZNMX89293

Comment: Ah, perhaps I wasn't clear. There will be more `name` rows in the future as well as `guild` rows. I'd like this to be flexible.

Comment: It’s flexible. You have just to use your own table, my `data` table is just a sample of your data (I thought this part didn’t need an explanation...)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I apologize. I misread your code. I'll try it out.

Comment: This is the schema
https://i.imgur.com/oAuY3AX.png
I tried to make your code work, but I couldn't get it to.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```
with t as (
      select 'Testing' as name, 431220877250658305 as owner, 422950512657432578 as guild union all
      select 'Testing' as name, 431220877250658305 as owner, 431220877250658305 as guild union all  
      select 'BFClannet' as name, 337583271787626503 as owner, 337583271787626503 as guild union all  
      select 'BFClannet' as name, 337583271787626503 as owner, 216908635987509249 as guild
     )
select coalesce(guild, name)
from ((select t.name, t.guild || (case when t.owner = t.guild then '*' else '' end) as guild
       from t
      ) union all
      (select distinct t.name, null
       from t
      )
     ) x
order by name, guild nulls first;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=efd93e926a118e49a00b0788a0cc639f) is a db<>fiddle.

The idea is to calculate rows that you want.  The biggest trick is in ordering them, so the name comes first.